# React router setup multiple routes files with headers and nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently working on a web project that has two main sections, a showcase site and a user site. In order to differentiate the two different sites, I need to split them into two setup files, each having a specific header. I have seen some solutions involving making an array and mapping it in the main file, however I didn't find any solution with nested routes and components.

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828033/react-js-multiple-routes-files-doesnt-work) except I need to implement nested routes and layout components

**Index.js**

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      {ShowcaseRoute}
      {UserRoute}
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

**Showcase Route**

```
export default function ShowcaseRoute () {
  
  const Layout = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer />
      </>);
  }

  return (
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
    </Route>
  );
}
```

**User Route**

```
export default function UserRoute () {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path='/auth'>
        <Route />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/user'>
        <Route />
      </Route>
    </>
  );
}
```

(The user route is currently incomplete and the reason for this question)

Comment: What is the issue or question here?

Comment: Sorry @DrewReese, I added a link to a similar problem that was solved. The issue is that the showcaseRoute and userRoute components aren't being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShowcaseRoute` and `UserRoute` are both React components. In React they are rendered ***as JSX***, e.g. `<ShowcaseRoute />` instead of `{ShowcaseRoute}`.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <ShowcaseRoute />
  <UserRoute />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Both `ShowcaseRoute` and `UserRoute` are rendering routes so they must wrap the `Route` components in the `Routes` component.

Note that I also moved the `Layout` component declaration out on it's own as it's generally an anti-pattern to declare React components inside other React components as they will be recreated each time the parent component renders/rerenders, resulting in the entire sub-ReactTree being remounted.

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default function ShowcaseRoute() {
  return (
    <Routes> // <-- wrap routes in Routes component
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function UserRoute() {
  return (
    <Routes> // <-- wrap routes in Routes component
      <Route path="/auth">
        ....
      </Route>
      <Route path="/user">
        ....
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-setup-multiple-routes-files-with-headers-and-nested-routes]